# Create pattern of difference of two arrays of objects and apply it to another array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, design-patterns, compare, difference

I have array of two different objects (which can contain additional arrays of objects):

```
var array1 = [{"x":10,"y":10},{"a":10,"b":10,"c":10}]
```

and another array:

```
var array2 = [{"x":10,"y":10},{"a":10,"b":25,"c":10}]
```

I need "what is different on second array":

```
var tmp = [{},{"b":25}] e.g.
```

and now update array1 with the pattern tmp

Can someone help me on this? Your time is greatly appreciated.

**SOLUTION:**

https://github.com/flitbit/diff :)

Comment: nice. what have you tried? and why first taking the difference for later updating?

Comment: Is it a given that each element of both arrays is an object? What happens if a key from a is not in b? What happens if a key from b is not in a?

Comment: I want to send updated positions to client(simple game) and reduce data stream so i want to send only changed properties

Comment: Eech ellement of array is object, but this object can contain array of another objects etc..
It can not happend then key from a is not in b.
Both of arrays are same, they can differ only in some properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let compareJSON = (a, b) => {
  let ret = {};

  for (let i in b) {
    if (!a.hasOwnProperty(i) || b[i] !== a[i]) {
      ret[i] = b[i];
    }
  }
  return ret;
};

let a = [{"x":10,"y":10},{"a":10,"b":10,"c":10}]
let b = [{"x":10,"y":10},{"a":10,"b":25,"c":10}]

let length = a.length > b.length ? a.length : b.length;
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  console.log(compareJSON(a[i], b[i]));
}
```